# jQuery UI Slider change class for each value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery UI Slider that has a range between 1-100. I want to change the class of a div for each value between 1-100.

I know there is a more efficient JavaScript method to switch classes and go through the values. Is there a better method other than the else if statement?

Any tips to make this more efficient appreciated.

```
$( '#slider-container' ).slider({
min: 1,
max: 100,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    if ((ui.value == 2)) { 
        $( ".number_100" ).toggleClass( 'number_102' );
    } else if ((ui.value == 3)) { 
        $( ".number_100" ).toggleClass( 'number_103' );
    }
}
});
```

or (but not sure how to find/remove last class added?)

```
<div class="position_100 number_101"></div>    

$( '.position_100' ).removeClass().addClass((ui.value<10) ? 'number_10'+ui.value : 'number_1'+ui.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bit long winded, but after checking the other answered it appeared that the `toggleClass` wasn't sufficient; solely because for every `slide` we're potentially adding a class, thus resulting in multiple "number classes" on the item, i.e. the class attribute value was: `number_101 number_102 number_103`. Instead, I'm assuming you're aftering simply the most recent `ui.value` change?

If that's the case it can be achieved using the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method within jQuery, and by simply remember what the most recent class was that was added, like so:

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
    if (div.data('lastClass')) {
        div.removeClass(div.data('lastClass'));                   
    }

    var newClass = ui.value < 10 ? 'number_10' + ui.value : 'number_1' + ui.value;
    div.data('lastClass', newClass).addClass(newClass);
}
```

I know it may seem a bit longer winded, but it does mean that we only have a single "number class" after sliding.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/bZmJ8/2/)

Comment: I like the removeClass/addClass and I added that (see top of post). I have never used .data before. How would I find lastClass?

Comment: `.data` is simply a way of storing information in a key/value pair format against an object. In this example we're storing the `lastClass` when adding a class; then upon changing it (i.e. the next call) we're checking to see if one has already been added, and removing it prior to updating it.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( ".number_100" ).toggleClass( 'number_10'+ui.value );
}
```

be more efficient? This assumes that your class names correspond to the slider values so that a value of 10 equals a class name of 'number_1010'.

Quick **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bZmJ8/)** using three classes.

Comment: I like this. I came up with a different version based on background image rather than adding all those classes:

Comment: Great, please consider upvoting this or selecting this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.value < 10) { 
        $( ".number_100" ).toggleClass( 'number_10'+ui.value );
    } else { 
        $( ".number_100" ).toggleClass( 'number_1'+ui.value );
    }
}
```

or:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
   $(".number_100").toggleClass((ui.value<10) ? 'number_10'+ui.value : 'number_1'+ui.value);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this simply add the classes `number_101`, `number_102`, `number_103`.. as you were scrolling along? Check the console of this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/bZmJ8/1/